# Getting the lengh of an JSON array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I am having a json file. I can get the data in the json file using

```
$.getJSON.json("mock/Insight72.json", function (jsondata) {
    response = jsondata.Data1;
    response2 = jsondata.Data2;
});
```

But I want to find the length of the Data1 and Data2. What should I do?

Here`s the JSON data(Only the Fruit Part)..

```
],
"Data1": {
    "kitchen selectives": [{
        "displayColor": "#DC143C",
            "numProducts": 1,
            "averagePrice": 25.99,
    }],
        "aroma": [{
        "displayColor": "#991F1F",
            "numProducts": 1,
            "averagePrice": 60.25,
    }, {
        "displayColor": "#DC143C",
            "numProducts": 1,
            "averagePrice": 46.19,
    }, ............
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `Data1` appears to be an `Object` (`{`...`}`), it'll only have a `length` if one was explicitly given as another key/value:

```
{
    "aroma": [],
    "length": 2
}
```

However, if you'd like to know the number of keys/properties it has, you can use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys):

```
var keyCountData1 = Object.keys(jsondata.Data1).length;
```

You can also retrieve the `length` of any `Array` (`[`...`]`) within `Data1`, such as `"aroma"`:

```
var aromas = jsondata.Data1.aroma.length;
```

Or, if you want to know the `length` of the Object as JSON:

```
var dataLength = JSON.stringify(jsondata.Data1).length;
```

Beyond that, however, you'll have to clarify exactly what "*length*" you're hoping for.

Answer (score 2):

To find out how many elements are in the `response` object, you can do something like:

```
var length = 0;
for (var key in response) {
    response.hasOwnProperty(key) && ++length;
}
```

If you want to find out the total length of all the arrays under it, you can do something like:

```
var length = 0;
for (var key in response) {
    response.hasOwnProperty(key) && length += response[key].length;
}
```

Comment: You should probably rewrite that to include an `if(response.hasOwnProperty(key))` instead of the `&&`-approach. That way, even the mortal js-developer might understand how it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use two different approaches

1. This one is not compatible with IE7 and 8. Look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) as well.

   ```
   var length = Object.keys(response).length;
   var length2 = Object.keys(response2).length;
   ```
2. This one will itterate through json and return length:

   ```
   function getJSONLegth(response) {
       var count = 0;
       for (var k in response) {
           count++;
       }
       return count;
   }    

   var length = getJSONLegth(response);
   var length2 = getJSONLegth(response2);
   ```

   Did it help you?